# Error A2149 while making a line using macros in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have an assignment to make a digital clock and it requires printing numbers from 0 to 9 similar to that on a seven segment display. So far I've made numbers without macros. Now I'm trying to make a horizontal line using one and I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
Include irvine32.inc

draw_row macro row_start, row_end, col_ 
movzx al, row_start
mov bl, col_
mov ecx, row_end

L1:
mov  dl,al  ;column
mov  dh,bl  ;row
call Gotoxy
mov edx, offset string1
call writestring

inc al
loop L1
endm

;draw_column macro _row, _col 

;endm 

.data
temp_col1 byte ?
temp_col2 byte ?
temp_row1 byte ?
temp_row2 byte ?


string1 byte "_" , 0
string2 byte "|" , 0
.code
main proc

mov temp_row1, 0
mov temp_row2, 5
mov temp_col1, 0
draw_row temp_row1, temp_row2 , temp_col1

call crlf

call dumpregs

;call clrscr

exit
main endp
end main          ;end program`
```

This code should print ----- 
Please help out with the errors. 
I'm new to macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the [error documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew5k718z.aspx) which says

> A byte register was specified to an instruction that cannot take it as the first operand.

This refers to `movzx al, row_start`. You can't zero extend into a byte register. You just want a `mov` there.

The other error is the reverse, you used `mov ecx, row_end` where `row_end` is a byte, so you do need a `movzx` there.

PS: None of these relate to macros, and in fact I don't see any reason to code this as a macro.

Comment: We're supposed to use macros. I was fine without them. 
Thank you. It works.